# How can I sum values from a group of elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I sum values from a group of elements using jQuery?

When I use `console.log` and the browser shows the result it is the sum of all values from the `div` elements. How can I sum my values in a condition that they have the same `class`?

```js
let sumPartOne = 0;
let sumPartTwo = 0;
let sumPartTree = 0;
let sumPartFour = 0;
let sumPartFive = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  $(`.part-${i}`).each(function() {
    sumPartOne += isNaN($(this).text()) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).text());
  })
}

console.log(sumPartOne);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part-1">10</div>
<div class="part-2">20</div>
<div class="part-3">30</div>
<div class="part-4">40</div>
<div class="part-5">50</div>

<div class="part-1">20</div>
<div class="part-2">30</div>
<div class="part-3">40</div>
<div class="part-4">50</div>
<div class="part-5">60</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bq0md39y/22/

Comment: Aren't you already doing it in the example?

Comment: what am I do is just sum all my values inside the `div`, I wanna make how to sum grouping by element class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you need to would be to build an object keyed by the `part-X` value. You can achieve that using a common class, a data attribute and `each()`, like this:

```js
let sum = {};
$('.part').each((i, el) => sum[el.dataset.group] = (sum[el.dataset.group] || 0) + parseInt(el.innerText, 10));

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part" data-group="part-1">10</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-2">20</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-3">30</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-4">40</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-5">50</div>

<div class="part" data-group="part-1">20</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-2">30</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-3">40</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-4">50</div>
<div class="part" data-group="part-5">60</div>
```

The benefit of this approach is that it's infinitely extensible simply by amending the HTML. You don't need to change the JS if any other groups of elements are added/removed.

Comment: thanks for awesome code, but I must read your code first, for the beginner like me it's a little difficult to read your code, but really I wanna say thanks to you, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment variables `sumPart{count}` based on iteration. For example when you are at "part-1" you want to increment `sumPartOne` and same for "part-2" you want to increment `sumPartTwo`

```
let sumPartOne = 0;
let sumPartTwo = 0;
let sumPartThree = 0;
let sumPartFour = 0;
let sumPartFive = 0;

function addition(part, i) {
   switch (part) {
     case 1:
       sumPartOne += isNaN(i) ? 0 : parseInt(i);
      
     case 2:
       sumPartTwo += isNaN(i) ? 0 : parseInt(i);
       
     case 3:
       sumPartThree += isNaN(i) ? 0 : parseInt(i)
       
     case 4:
       sumPartFour += isNaN(i) ? 0 : parseInt(i);
       
     case 5:
       sumPartFive += isNaN(i) ? 0 : parseInt(i);
   }
}

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        $(`.part-${i}`).each(function () {
        addition(i, $(this).text())
    })
}

console.log('1', sumPartOne);
console.log('2', sumPartTwo);
console.log('3', sumPartThree);
console.log('4', sumPartFour);
console.log('5', sumPartFive);
```

p.s.
This way you can use switch condition where you will apply same logic that you are using in your example but we will increment values based on part on which we are iterating. You will have values incremented properly for each summation than having all increments on `sumPartOne` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using five differently named variables to store the sum of the five parts, you can use `switch` to store the sums.

```js
let sumPartOne   = 0;
let sumPartTwo   = 0;
let sumPartThree = 0;
let sumPartFour  = 0;
let sumPartFive  = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    $(`.part-${i}`).each(function () {
        sum += isNaN($(this).text()) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).text());
    })
    switch(i) {
        case 1: sumPartOne   = sum; break;
        case 2: sumPartTwo   = sum; break;
        case 3: sumPartThree = sum; break;
        case 4: sumPartFour  = sum; break;
        case 5: sumPartFive  = sum; break;
    }
}

console.log(sumPartOne, sumPartTwo, sumPartThree, sumPartFour, sumPartFive);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part-1">10</div>
<div class="part-2">20</div>
<div class="part-3">30</div>
<div class="part-4">40</div>
<div class="part-5">50</div>

<div class="part-1">20</div>
<div class="part-2">30</div>
<div class="part-3">40</div>
<div class="part-4">50</div>
<div class="part-5">60</div>
```

However, it would be better to store all the sums in an object.

```js
let sums = {};

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    let sum = 0;
    $(`.part-${i}`).each(function () {
        sum += isNaN($(this).text()) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).text());
    })
    sums[`.part-${i}`] = sum;
}

console.log(sums);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part-1">10</div>
<div class="part-2">20</div>
<div class="part-3">30</div>
<div class="part-4">40</div>
<div class="part-5">50</div>

<div class="part-1">20</div>
<div class="part-2">30</div>
<div class="part-3">40</div>
<div class="part-4">50</div>
<div class="part-5">60</div>
```

Comment: it's cool thanks for your suggest, so I must use `switch-case` for my case? Is I can't use `if-case` in my code?